# Datafram add new column with condition and base on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have datafram of customer rfm.

[Customer Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cphi5.png)

sample data is here:

```
df_cust = pd.Dataframe(
 'CustNo' = [001, 002, 003, 004],
 'Recency' = [5,10,200,150],
 'Frequency' = [1, 3, 10, 1]
)
```

I would like to create new column is 'score_recency'. I have 2 function calculate score too(Normal i use lambda function to create columns pandas.)

```
def cal_new_cust(recency):
    return score # logic code with new cust frequency = 1
```

```
def cal_old_cust(recency):
   return score # logic code with old cust frequency > 1
```

How i create column 'score_recency' by apply 2 func calculate score of each customer base on column Frequency ?

Comment: Please add the expected output too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with DataFrame.apply(). sample follows:

```
df_cust = pd.DataFrame(
    {
 'CustNo' : ['001', '002', '003', '004'],
 'Recency' : [5,10,200,150],
 'Frequency' : [1, 3, 10, 1]}
)
```

stub function:

```
def cal_new_cust(recency):
    return recency+1 # logic code with new cust frequency = 1

def cal_old_cust(recency):
    return recency-1 # logic code with old cust frequency > 1
```

New code: based on frequency, the function will call new vs old customer function.

```
def decision_maker(pair):
    if pair['Frequency'] == 1:
        return cal_new_cust(pair['Recency'])
    else:
        return cal_old_cust(pair['Recency'])
df_cust['score_recency']=df_cust.apply(decision_maker,axis=1)# send as a row pair
df_cust
```

yes, can pass value through `apply` function, pls refer [apply with parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

so it will look like

```
def cal_new_cust(recency,mypar=None):
    print(mypar)
    return recency+1 # logic code with new cust frequency = 1

def cal_old_cust(recency,mypar=None):
    print(mypar)
    return recency-1 # logic code with old cust frequency > 1


def decision_maker(pair,**kwargs):
    print(f" June:{kwargs['june']} july:{kwargs['july']}")
    if pair['Frequency'] == 1:
        return cal_new_cust(pair['Recency'],kwargs['june'])
    else:
        return cal_old_cust(pair['Recency'],kwargs['july'])
df_cust['score_recency']=df_cust.apply(decision_maker,june=30, july=20,axis=1)
df_cust
```

Comment: How do i pass agrument into function decision_maker(pair)

Comment: `df_cust.apply` will move the row-level argument to the function. that is the reason that `pair['Frequency']` is used in `decision_maker`. so pair is equivalent to a row of dataframe with a header.

Comment: `def decision_maker(row, param1, param2): .....`
`and in df.apply(decision_maker(param1, param2), axis=1)` ?

Comment: you don't have to add any parameter. you are already getting the parameter value in `decision_maker` which is passing 'Recency' value to your `cal_new_cust` and `cal_old_cust` function. to prove that, cust functions are getting 'Recency' I returned recency+1 and recency-1 from them.  I would recommend that pls run this program as such to understand how pandas apply function fed the data. And if you need to build logic in cal_new_cust and cal_old_cust, go ahead as it already has the needed parameter 'recency'.

Comment: Sr sir. Please let me explain more detail, i would like to pass another params  not row in dataframe:
`def decision_maker(row, param1, param2): `
`if row.frequency > 1: return cal_old_cust(row.recency, param1)`
`else: return cal_new_cust(row.recency, param2)`

Comment: added a new use case. hope it will help.

Comment: `def cal_new_cust(recency, median): if recency > median: return 2 else: return 1`.
`def cal_old_cust(recency, value): if recency > value: return 4 else: return 3`
In function cal_new_cust() and cal_old_cust() i have param to calculate score recency of customer.